# php email script wont run on cron

Tags: php, cron

I have this script to email some stats running through a cron but it keeps falling down at this point on the cron. Could anyone help please, not my script, it was working, ive just taken over and a bit of a newbie to this.

PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(http://www.mydomain.co.uk/folder1/folder2/emails/jl_jobs_progress.email.php?do=user&name=barrytibbetts&fullname=BARRY+TIBBETTS&jobs=1): failed to open stream: Connection timed out in /var/www/folder1/folder2/classes/emails.class.php on line 220

line 220 is point out below----

```
public function doJobsWaitingAlert($p_jobs_waiting,$p_cons_email,$p_cons_user,$p_cons_fullname) 
{
    try 
    {
        $this->m_mail->ClearAllRecipients();

        $this->m_mail->Priority = 1; //high
        $this->m_mail->Subject = sprintf("%s %s Jobs Require Immediate Attention", $p_cons_fullname, $p_jobs_waiting);
        $this->m_mail->MsgHTML(file_get_contents(sprintf("%semails/jl_jobs_progress.email.php?do=user&name=%s&fullname=%s&jobs=%s",
            _URL,
            urlencode($p_cons_user),
            urlencode(strtoupper($p_cons_fullname)),
            urlencode($p_jobs_waiting)

            )
    // LINE 220   ) 
        );

        $this->m_mail->AltBody = sprintf("To view this alert you need to enable HTML display on your email, or you can view this page online at %s",_URL);

        if (_NOTIFY_LIVE) {
            $this->m_mail->AddAddress($p_cons_email,$p_cons_fullname);
        } else {
            $this->m_mail->AddAddress(_NOTIFY_TEST_EMAIL,$p_cons_fullname);
        }
        $this->m_mail->Send();

        return 1;
    } catch (phpmailerException $e) {
        echo $e->errorMessage();
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this code from `emails.class.php` or `jl_jobs_progress.email.php`?

Comment: Sometimes script need more than 30 second, maybe you can play around with `set_time_limit(10);`

Comment: where is this this? php.ini